# How to stop the PriorityBinding's thread

Tags: wpf, binding, multithreading

Listbox's ItemsSource is TList

in XImage's Dispose method, 
How do I stop the thread which load the thumbnail?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
...
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <PriorityBinding>
                                        <Binding Path="Thumbnail" IsAsync="True" />
                                        <Binding Path="DefaultImage"/>
                                    </PriorityBinding>
                                </Image.Source>
....                                
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I am curious - what do you want to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: I don't want the thread to keep updating images after I clear listbox's items.